# How insert and publish news in joomla 3.0 from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, rss

I try insert some articles from a PHP script but i don´t get it. I need to know what fields are required and how I can create the query to do it.

Now, I´m write the next code:

```
foreach($RSS_DOC->channel->item as $RSSitem){

    $alias    = md5($RSSitem->title);
    $fetch_date = date("Y-m-j G:i:s"); //NOTE: we don't use a DB SQL function so its database independent
    $item_title = $RSSitem->title;
    $item_description = $RSSitem->description;
    $item_date  = date("Y-m-j G:i:s", strtotime($RSSitem->pubDate));
    $item_url   = $RSSitem->link;

    // Does record already exist? Only insert if new item...

    $item_exists_sql = "SELECT alias FROM jos_content where alias = ".$alias;
    $item_exists = mysqli_query($enlace,$item_exists_sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($item_exists)<1){
        $mensaje = "<p>".$item_description."</p>Publicado: ".$item_date."<br/><a href='".$item_url."'>Ver noticia original</a>";
        $item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO jos_content(title, alias, introtext, state, catid, created, created_by, access,featured) VALUES ('" .$item_title. "', '" . $alias. "', '" . $mensaje. "',1, 10,'".$fetch_date."',448,1,1)";
        $insert_item = mysqli_query($enlace,$item_insert_sql);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the Joomla framework when you're running this script or is it run outside of the website server?

Comment: i don´t use Joomla Framework, i put this code into an article and run when website is complete loaded. I have access to phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok, the issue with your current approach is when you create articles in Joomla it also creates a corresponding reference in the assets table for ACL purposes. I've had to programmatically create articles many times and can post the code I used, but it relies on loading some core classes, which handles all the "extra" work behind the scenes.

Comment: You should be using the API to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

First order of business is to create the article data object.  I use a method to scrub out an existing id or asset_id references in case I'm migrating article data from one instance to another.  This could be replaced by your logic to build out the article data object as well.  Just be sure to use an associative array:

```
function processArticleData($obj) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }

    $data['id'] = 0;
    unset($data['asset_id']);

    return $data;
}
```

Next you load the JTable content class, bind the data and save.  Joomla does all the rest:

```
function addArticle($obj) {
    // Initialise variables;
    $data       = processModuleData($obj);
    $table      = &JTable::getInstance('content');

    // Bind the data.
    if (!$table->bind($data))
    {
        echo "<h1>Error Binding Article Data</h1>";
        return false;
    }

    // Check the data.
    if (!$table->check())
    {
        echo "<h1>Error Checking Article Data</h1>";
        return false;
    }

    // Store the data.
    if (!$table->store())
    {
        echo "<h1>Error Storing Article Data</h1>";
        return false;
    }

    return $table->get('id');
}
```

The benefits of this approach is it removes any "guessing" about required fields or potential errors, as if there is an issue with the data Joomla will throw an exception or error stating what the issue was.  If you wanted/needed to get real fancy, you could even load the JForm object for content, bind your data to it and then validate before binding to the JTable object.

Creating the data object has only two requirements.  The first is to use an associative array and the second all key names match columns in the #__content table.  An example data object would look like this:

```
 $data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'alias' => $alias,
    'introtext' => $introtext,
    'fulltext' => $fulltext,
    'catid' => $catid,
    'images' => '',
    'urls' => '',
    'attribs' => '',
    'metakey' => '',         
    'metadesc' => '',
    'metadata' => '',
    'language' => '',
    'xreference' => '',         
    'created' => JFactory::getDate()->toSql(),
    'created_by' => JFactory::getUser()->id,
    'publish_up' => JFactory::getDate()->toSql(),
    'publish_down' => JFactory::getDbo()->getNullDate(),
    'state' => 1
);
```

I use some more Joomla helper functions to make my job easier, but this should provide a good starting point for you to get the ball rolling.

*** EDIT ***

Noticed a typo which I corrected.  Not sure if you copy/pasted but switch the below line for the array declaration above and test again:

```
    $data       = processModuleData($obj);
```

Comment: How i create the object? i´m not able to join it

Comment: see my above edit, I created a data object as an example you could use.

Comment: How about setting the article as Featured? It needs to be inserted into #__content_frontpage table as well, is there an API or observer for that just like for tags (JTableObserverTags)?

Answer (score 0):

This script should do it....assuming it exists in the root of your site:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define ('JPATH_BASE', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\mysiteroot');

    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
}
function getContentTable($type = 'Content', $prefix = 'JTable', $config = array())
{
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}
function addArticle($title, $alias)
{
    $table = getContentTable();
    $table->title = $title;
    $table->alias = $alias;
    $table->catid = 2;
    $table->state = 1;
    // and so on!
    // then save it
    $table->store();
}
$result = addArticle("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: how is the object from: `code define ('JPATH_BASE', 'c:\\wamp\\www\\plethora'); `

Comment: Ok, I tried this solution but title is not insert, any solution?

Comment: You;ll have to give me some errors to work with...this works as expected from a regular joomla site.

Comment: I got it, but now i have featured as 1 (this must show in main frontpage) but I need update jos_content_frontpage to show it. How I can??

Comment: i believe that all you need to do is include `$table->featured = 1;`

Comment: That is done, article appears with star in administrator but not is referenced in jos_content_frontpage

Comment: I don't use Featured articles, but scanning the core code, I found this function in `administrator\components\com_content\models\article.php` that Joomla uses that you should be able to incorporate somehow into your script: `public function featured($pks, $value = 0)`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!! I need it, Can you help me how include in my script?? I´m a beginner, Thanks again